# Games with simple graphics like Dots or 2048?

Tags: 2d, android, mobile

I want to try making an Android game, but I'm bad at making graphics. I want to make a game with very simple graphics and I'm looking for inspiration. What are some games like Dots or 2048?

Comment: Questions that ask for lists are usually not welcome here, unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think best way to find inspiration would be to look through android store (if you only want to prectise code and not sell it). Some I can think of:

Hundreds

Lazors

7x7

Pong

Any Pool/Snooker etc

Chess

Tic Tac Toe

Bowman

---

edit:

UnBlock Me

Tetris?

Breakout